# Firebase - custom url - avoid *.firebaseio.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase with custom url. However the websocket connection uses still wss://.firebaseio.com/.

Is it possible to move this configuration to the custom domain?

also 'verifyToken' and getAccountInfo is always through https://www.googleapis.com/.

thank you

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Why does the destination of the websocket matter for your app?

Comment: Our application is used within corporate networks, which block *.firebaseio.com as well as cloudfunctions...

Answer (score 0):

No - unfortunately that's not possible. What you're asking would involve rewriting some of the internal logic hard-coded on Firebase's servers... and Firebase doesn't expose that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

While this may be possible, it's not a recommended solution.  You won't be able to achieve this purely by configuration alone, and it is just speculation about whether or not it will work.

When Firebase initializes, there is a configuration parameter for the destination of the websocket it establishes.  Since you haven't said which platform you're using, I'll leave it up to you to read the documentation to see which parameter you have to change in your call to initialize Firebase.

After you change this parameter, you will need to have some proxy service at the destination to route all that traffic to the actual websocket destination at Google.  This is a broad topic, and you will have to figure out how you want to implement this proxy.